# How do I connect my GoDaddy domain to an Azure VM server?

Tags: azure, dns, cname, nameservers, a-records

I have inherited an Azure VM with CentOS running a web server. I can access this by going to the IP address with port 8080 (let's call it 12.34.567.890:8080).

I have the domain example.app registered with GoDaddy. Now I need to connect them up. I realise I need to set up DNS records, but I'm not sure whether to do that by changing the name servers on GoDaddy to the Azure ones, and then setting up the DNS Zone on Azure, or whether to keep the name servers at GoDaddy and set up the DNS Zone there to point to Azure (the latter is how it's currently set up). I've tried a few things, but no joy so far.

Currently there seems to be a mixture of both (someone else worked on this before me, and I'm not sure what's default in either case).

So, at GoDaddy we have:

```
    Using Default name servers:
    ns77.domaincontrol.com
    ns78.domaincontrol.com

    A records:
    @   12.34.567.890 (the IP of the Azure server)
    *   12.34.567.890

    CNAME:
    www    @

    NS:
    @   ns77.domaincontrol.com
    @   ns78.domaincontrol.com

    SOA:
    @   Primary nameserver: ns77.domaincontrol.com
```

I can edit the A and CNAME records, but not the NS or SOA ones.

At Azure (in DNS Zone) I have:

```
Resource group: www.example.app
Name Server 1: ns1-04.azure-dns.com
Name Server 2: ns2-04.azure-dns.net
Name Server 3: ns3-04.azure-dns.org
Name Server 4: ns4-04.azure-dns.info

Name    Type   TTL      Value                      Alias resource type      Alias target

@       A      3600     -                          Public IP Address        example-prod-ip

@       NS     172800   ns1-04.azure-dns.com.
                        ns2-04.azure-dns.net.
                        ns3-04.azure-dns.org.
                        ns4-04.azure-dns.info.

@       SOA    3600     Email: azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com
                        Host: ns1-04.azure-dns.com.
                        Refresh: 3600
                        Retry: 300
                        Expire: 2419200
                        Minimum TTL: 300
                        Serial number: 1
```

Again I have to option of editing or deleting the A record, but not the others.

If I try to go to the domain via the browser, I get the following:

```
Using 12.34.567.890:8080 - works fine
Using 12.34.567.890 - "Safari can't open the page because the server isn't responding"
Using example.app or www.example.app or http://www.example.app - "Safari can't open the page because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server"
```

I don't know whether the domain being just "example.app" is making a difference too.  What can I try next?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, By default, the web browser access the web server via using HTTP port 80 or HTTPS port 443. If you use a non-default port 8080, you need to add the port when you access your websites like `http://12.34.567.890:8080`, `http://www.example.app:8080` or `http://example.app:8080`.

You can **select** to use Azure DNS to host your domain, but this is not a must thing to do. Your domain is still registered on GoDaddy. Once you [host your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns), you need to add the Azure name server to your domain register instead of using default name servers in GoDaddy. In my impression, after you host your domain in Azure DNS, you can not edit the records in the GoDaddy.

Then, to map your custom domain to your website, you need to add the `A` or `CNAME` records in the domain DNS zone. For `A` record, you need to add `@` and `*` with type `A` and point to the VM’s public IP Address. For `CNAME`records, you need to add `www` with type CNAME and point to the VM's FQDN name. See [creating a FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn#create-a-fqdn).

Finally, in this case, I see that you have got the correct A records configuration in your domain provider. This should work. You don't need to create an Azure DNS zone more. So you are using `12.34.567.890:8080` fine. You just need to add the 8080 port when you access the websites in other web browsers. If you don't want to add the port each time, you can change the webserver listening port and restrict the website accessible in a limited source IP via the [network security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview) attached to the subnet of Azure VM.

```
A records:
    @   12.34.567.890 (the IP of the Azure server)
    *   12.34.567.890
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll stick with the GoDaddy nameservers. So my A records there are the same as before. I created a FQDN which is example.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com (where "example" is my app name).  So I made a CNAME record called www which points to example.ukwest.cloudapp.azure.com. So that's all that's in GoDaddy apart from their defaults.

Comment: In Azure I removed all A and CNAME records from the DNS zone, but there are still NS and SOA records for @ which point to Azure nameservers.  It won't let me change those.

Comment: I don't want to add 8080 each time, so after some Googling I created an Inbound Security Rule which has Source: Service Tag; Source Service Tag: Internet; Source Port Ranges: *; Destination: Any; Destination Port Ranges: 80; Protocol: TCP and Action: Allow.

Comment: I can still access by 12.34.567.890:8080 but 12.34.567.890 (without port number) give the error "can't connect". "example.app" gives "can't establish a secure connection".

Comment: You also need to change the listening port in your web application and restart your service when you change the port..